# Проблема в слоте: ошибка: undefined reference to `check_t_value(int)'

Tags: c++, qt, функции, signal

У меня есть обычная функция check_t_value(int T_VALUE) и слот slot_conside()

Я хочу, чтобы в слоте у меня была вызвана check_t_value(int T_VALUE) и передала T_VALUE в int t_value (она находится в slot_conside()).

У меня получился вот такой код:

```
int MainWindow::check_t_value(int T_VALUE) {
//...подсчитывается T_VALUE
    return T_VALUE;
}

void MainWindow::slot_conside() {
   ...
   int t_value;
   int check_t_value(int T_VALUE); //вызываю функцию
   check_t_value(t_value);         //передаю значение
   ans = s_value / t_value;
}
```

При компиляции выдаёт ошибку:

> undefined reference to `check_t_value(int)'

Comment: `int check_t_value(int T_VALUE); //вызываю функцию` - это объявление новой функции (которое заставляет компилятор искать функцию `check_t_value` вместо `MainWindow::check_t_value`), а вызов это как раз `check_t_value(t_value);`. Кроме того, префикс (и суффикс) `t_` обычно используется для имен типов, а не для переменных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int check_t_value(int T_VALUE); //вызываю функцию
```

Это вы так думаете, что вызываете... Это - объявление функции `check_t_value` (именно `check_t_value`, а не `MainWindow::check_t_value`). И именно ее пытается найти компилятор для вызова в следующей строке.

И, конечно же, не находит.

О чем и сообщает.

Comment: кстати, почему, я получаю в T_VALUE нужное значение, а в t_value уже пишет совсем другое число? Т.е. получается, что функция справляется, а в слоте что-то не так?

Comment: Простите, не очень понял вопрос. Вот здесь `check_t_value(t_value);` `t_value` не получает нужное значение? Но вы же передаете его по значению, т.е. функция работает с его копией. Я вообще не вижу, зачем вы передаете его в функцию - поскольку в этом значении какой-то мусор. Но поскольку функция возвращает нужное значение, подозреваю, что вам нужно `t_value = check_t_value(t_value);`. И еще раз подумайте - вам точно нужно передавать значение в `check_t_value()`? Оно в ней где-то используется?

Comment: Всё правильно поняли и всё правильно показали =))! А вот я не очень понял Вашtuj вопрос... Я вроде и передаю значение в вызов для присвоения значения `t_value`.

Comment: В вашем коде,где написано `//...подсчитывается T_VALUE` - начальное, передаваемое в функцию значение используется в подсчетах? Не для того, чтобы вернуть, а именно значение, передаваемое в функцию? Если нет - то лучше иметь функцию `check_t_value()`; если да - то вы передаете в нее мусор (неинициализированное значение) и она и считает какой-то мусор. Вот я и просил вас определиться...

Comment: Конечно, значение присваивается из LineEdit'а, потом только возвращается